# protractor issue after update chromium version

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, chromium, e2e-testing

I just updated my chromium version and the "getAttribute" always returns null, does anybody knows why? (before this update was working fine)

```
CHROMIUM_REVISION=884014

element(by.id(elementId)).getAttribute('value').then((value) => {
                console.log(value); // <-- null
            });
```

Comment: check `chromedriver` is compatible with the new `chromium`

Comment: this question has been asked at least 3 times this week

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with ChromeDriver 91, first reported in the [Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107&start=300) on May 3rd 2021.

I've described the problem and possible solutions/workarounds in more detail in [this article](https://janmolak.com/chrome-91-might-break-your-tests-507309b9b2cd).

In short, the Chromium team believes that a [recent change](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3746) to the ChromeDriver attribute endpoint has negatively impacted the behaviour of the `GetElementAttribute` command, which now leads to `WebElement.getAttribute` method returning `null` instead of the actual value of the attribute.

The issue affects tools using the `JsonWireProtocol`, such as [Selenium WebDriver 3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver), which Protractor uses [under the hood](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/df3dd6400e3a4792ff9f7a58849d2a5eed6e1483/package.json#L26).

The solution recommended by the Chromium team is to use Selenium WebDriver 4 instead, and there's an [ongoing effort](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5519) to make Protractor use that too (if you're on GitHub, please consider upvoting this ticket). A thing to note is that Selenium WebDriver 4 [deprecates a number of APIs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/deprecated-list.html), so tests will need to be updated to avoid using those (i.e. `browser.actions()`).

A Selenium WebDriver 3-compatible fix [has been proposed too](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107#c3), but isn't available at the time of writing (June 8th 2021).

If you'd like to use Chromium/ChromeDriver 91 with Protractor before the official fixes are available you have three options:

### Use W3C protocol

You can explicitly enable support for W3C protocol (instead of the affected JsonWireProtocol) in `protractor.conf.js`:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        w3c: true,
        args: [
            '--headless',
        ]
    },
}
```

**Warning**: Some APIs, like `browser.actions()` are not compatible with the W3C mode and will break when this mode is enabled.

### Fall back to injecting JavaScript

You can change your tests to fall back to retrieving the attribute value via JavaScript when `getAttribute()` returns `null`.

```
const attribute = await element.getAttribute(name).then(value => {
    if (value !== null) {
        return value;
    }
    
    return browser.executeScript(`
        function getAttribute(webElement, attributeName) {
            return webElement.getAttribute(attributeName);        
        })
    `, element, name);
})
```

This is similar to how [Serenity/JS acceptance testing framework](https://serenity-js.org/) does it [under the hood](https://serenity-js.org/modules/protractor/).

### Use Protractor with Serenity/JS

I've already implemented the above fallback strategy in [Serenity/JS](https://serenity-js.org) (view on [GitHub](https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js)), so if you're using Protractor with Serenity/JS, you need to updated any `@serenity-js/*` modules to version [2.29.0](https://serenity-js.org/changelog#2-29-0-2021-06-06-) and it will just work with Chromium 91.

For example, if you have a widget like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="confirm" />
```

With Serenity/JS and Protractor, you'd retrieve any of the widget's attributes as follows:

```
import { actorCalled } from '@serenity-js/core';
import { Ensure, equals } from '@serenity-js/assertions';
import { Target } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

const confirmation = Target.the('confirmation checkbox')
    .located(by.id('confirm'));

// in the test:

actorCalled('Alice').attemptsTo(
    Ensure.that(
        Attribute.of(confirmation).called('checked'),
        equals('true')
    ),
);
```

To get started with Serenity/JS and Protractor:

- check out the [intro video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djPMf-n93Rw)
- have a look at the [example projects](https://github.com/serenity-js) on GitHub
- ask any questions on the [community chat](https://gitter.im/serenity-js/Lobby)
- or here on StackOverflow, tagging them with `[serenity-js]`

Full disclosure, I'm the author of Serenity/JS

Comment: explicitly enable support for W3C protocol:`'goog:chromeOptions': {
        w3c: true,
        args: [
            '--headless',
        ]
    },` gives me: `[17:13:34] E/launcher - invalid argument: 'capabilities' must be a JSON object
[17:13:34] E/launcher - InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: 'capabilities' must be a JSON object`  chromedriver: chromedriver_91.0.4472.101

Comment: The above change : `goog:chromeOptions ` to `google:chromeOptions`

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me

I found a temp workaround that just worked with chrome `91.0.4472.114` on mac

The problem described here is actually a bug in chromedriver https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107 so it is not Protractor problem only

While it's being worked on, **you can use chromedriver version 90**. Works like a charm. The latest version available is here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_90.0.4430

You can downgrade chromedriver by running this command

```
webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

Note sometimes you have global, project local and Protractor specific installations of webdriver-manager. The command I gave will install chromedriver globally. In order to install locally you need to find the path to your webdriver-manager and run command like this

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

And some of you may need to run command in `sudo` mode. Keep it in mind