# Value attribute not present on input element | AngularJS, Chrome 91, Protractor

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, automated-tests, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

After updating chrome driver to ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19

The `value` attribute have dissapeared from the `input` elements. Protractor cannot access the value attribute.

```
    let x = await xDiv.getEl("#xInput").getAttribute('value');

    // x = null
```

Using the Chrome Dev Tools, I am also not able to see the `value` attribute of any input element in the markup.

Using AngularJS 1.5.8 and Protractor/Selenium 3.141.59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you described is actually a bug in chromedriver https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1205107. It happened because of the change in chrome browser related to W3C compliance

As you can see, the plan is to fix the bug, however it is still in progress.

Meanwhile, I recommend you 2 workarounds:

1. **you can use chromedriver version 90**. The latest version available is here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_90.0.4430

I know that under normal circumstances this would throw incompatibility error, but somehow chromedriver 90 works with chrome 91.

You can downgrade chromedriver by running this command

```
webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

Note sometimes you have global, project local and Protractor specific installations of webdriver-manager. The command I gave will install chromedriver globally. In order to install locally you need to find the path to your webdriver-manager and run command like this

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome 90.0.4430.24
```

And some of you may need to run command in `sudo` mode. Keep it in mind

2. Instead of `elem.getAttribute('value')` try to go with `browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].value', elem);` multiple users claimed it works for them

Additionally, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67888592/9150146 that proposes more hacky solutions