# getText() returns blank and getAttribut('textContent') returns null | in chrome v91

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

getText() returns blank and getAttribute('textContent') returns null | in chrome v91 and on Mac machine.

getAttribute('textContent') works fine on Windows Chrome 91, but on mac and in chrome browser - its null and our scripts are failing in Mac machine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a missing delay / wait issue?

Comment: No, just verified with adding delay/wait and the returns empty string still.

Answer (score 0):

these might be different problems:

1. `getText` return an empty string if the element is not visible, not scrolled to, etc.
2. for `null` problem, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68075074/9150146

Comment: Thanks and yes, no issues with chromedriver v90 and the issue with v91. So only solution is to downgrade chromedriver version?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved with latest chromedriver, getAttribute('innerText') and getAttribute('textContent') that has given null in chromedriver v91, is working fine with latest v92.