# Get value from input box is not working protractor

Tags: xpath, protractor

I tried verifying xpath in console i.e

```
$x("//input[contains(@data-bind,'selectedParentKpi')]")[0].value
```

o/p :-   "12M Rolling MTBF (Days)"

So I am getting value in console. I am trying get data from my protractor test script as below

```
element(by.xpath("//input[contains(@data-bind,'selectedParentKpi')]")).getAttribute('value').then(function (text){
    console.log(text);
    cb();
})
```

IN test script I am getting null. Can anyone suggest what is the equavalent of $x("//input[contains(@data-bind,'selectedParentKpi')]")[0].value in protractor script

Comment: try `//input[@data-bind[contains(.,'selectedParentKpi')]]` as xpath

Comment: which chome and chromedriver you're using? 91?

Comment: I am using chrome version -91.  tried above xpath but still I am getting value as null.  <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $root.selectedParentKpi()" readonly="readonly">        this input box gets data from javascript . But how can we read data using protractor

Comment: this question has been answered dozen of times in the last month. This behavior is a bug in chromedriver. There is a workaround described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68075074/9150146